# mapStateToProps called twice

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

This is my first post so apologies if I miss anything or this is long-winded. I'm working on a udemy tutorial to create a form (using redux-form) with a couple text inputs where the user has the ability to click next and view their form values before submitting.  The code below is the "review" page of the form.
The intent is to pull the form values from state and add them to the SurveyFormReview component's props, however, I'm getting an error "cannot read property 'values' of undefined" when clicking the next button (which displays SurveyFormReview).  I've figured out that mapStateToProps is getting called twice but I can't figure out why.  When I've found other instances of this issue people have said this is caused by having another component nested within the component calling mapStateToProps, but I don't have that issue here.  What I can say is that the parent component, which holds the surveyForm and surveyFormReview components, initializes state as well.  This is for setting the flag that determines whether to show surveyForm or surveyFormReview.  Any thoughts?

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import formFields from './formFields';

const SurveyFormReview = ({ onCancel, formValues }) => {
// Grabs input field labels and names from external formFields array and inserts
// user values from formValues.
const reviewFields = _.map(formFields, field => {
    return (
        <div key={field.name}>
            <label>{field.label}</label>
            <div>
                {formValues[field.name]}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
});

return (
    <div>
        <h5>Please confirm your entries</h5>
        {reviewFields}
        <button className="yellow darken-3 btn-flat" onClick={onCancel}>
            Back
        </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return { formValues: state.form.surveyForm.values };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SurveyFormReview);
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(state)` in `mapStateToProps` return? Can you show the action that handles adding the form values to the reducer? I'm gonna guess that there is a second action that is causing the second `mapStateToProps` call.

Comment: Here's what the console.log spits out for state the first time.  You can see that 'form' has the surveyForm object, which contains the values:

`{auth: {…}, form: {…}}
  auth: {_id: "5a2ee53b593de87ae0656aba", googleId: 
    "118072951518725963579", __v: 0, credits: 3}
  form: {surveyForm: {…}}`

The second time it's called the form object is empty.  I didn't have to create a an action for adding the form values, I think redux-form takes care of that under the hood.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.  Had a dyslexic moment.  Thanks though!